# jQuery two "paged" nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav, navbar

This is a really long shot but I am going to try and explain as best as I can.

I currently have a site which has a navbar.

The Navbar looks like this: http://grab.by/dcDK.

My problem is that when I create too many navbar links it simply overflows: http://grab.by/dcDO

Would there be a way to make it so that if there is too many nav links then a little button appears at the end of the navbar ( > ) and when a user clicks this button the navbar slides to the next page where there are more nav links (the ones which overflowed).

I know its a long shot but I have searched everywhere and cannot find any solutions or hints. Below is a reduced code for my navbar:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
                        <div id="bottom-bar">
                            <div class="navigation"><li><div class="shadow"><a class="category" id="link_413" style="" href="#!/Shows">Our Shows</a><ul style="margin-left: -88px; display: none; "><li><a class="subnav" id="link_414" style="" href="#!/TheVault">The Vault</a></li></ul></div></li></div>
                            <div id="nav-arrow" style="left: 25px; "></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="subnav"></div>
                        <div id="subnavlinks"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You could use `.width()` or `.height()` on the navbar, somehow, to detect when it's exceeding its desired dimensions. Then chop off the last element, add an arrow, and keep chopping until it's the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom scrollbar for this but involves a lot of HTML/CSS experience:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller